# Python storing user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't have a working code at all for this, but if I wanted to take user input and store it, and then take a different input and store that to the same list (Like a site storing login information of it's members and associating it when they want to log back in) how would I do this in python?
I have this short little code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="")
w.pack()

User_info = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("User Information", "What is your name?")
def List(List_name):
    List_name = []
    List_name.append(User_info)
    return List_name
print List
```

yet this produces this result: function List at 0x7fdf1fa0f668

instead of (for instance) Johnny

Comment: So you want to basically store a username and password?

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the function so you are seeing a reference to the function, you also need to pass parameter:

```
print List(param)
```

What you really want is to remove the parameter and just call the function:

```
User_info = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("User Information", "What is your name?")
def List():
    List_name = []
    List_name.append(User_info)
    return List_name
print List()
```

Or simply:

```
User_info = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("User Information", "What is your name?")
def List():
    return [List_name]
print List()
```

A simple example of taking and saving the input to a file, obviously real usernames and passwords would need to be stored a lot more securely:

```
master = Tk()
l = Label(master, text="Username")
l.pack()
 # create Entry for user
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
l2 = Label(master, text="Password")
l2.pack()
# create Entry for pass and show * when user types their password
e2 = Entry(master,show="*")
e2.pack()
e.focus_set()

# callback function to save the username and password
def callback():
    with open("data.txt","a")as f:
        f.write("{},{}\n".format(e.get(),e2.get()))

# command set to callback when button is pressed
b = Button(master, text="Save", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Obviously you should be verifying the user actually entered something for both and in the real word you would have to see if the username was taken etc..

Comment: nice much more constructive than my answer im sure :P :) +1

Comment: And how do I store this and add more to the list?

Comment: Do you actually want to take a username and password?

Comment: Yea, I wanna take username and password

Comment: Ok then there are simpler ways, I will add an example in a few minutes

Comment: Okay, and would you be able to show me how to encrypt the info once saved?

Comment: `"".join(map(operator.xor,zip(cycle(password_key),my_text_to_encrypt))`

Answer (score 2):

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="")
w.pack()

print list(iter( lambda x:tkSimpleDialog.askstring("User Information", "What is your name?"),""))
```

will print all the names you give it until you give it no strings

Comment: I missed the multiple names!